# How can I completely reload a view so that viewDidLoad gets run again?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to reload my view so that `viewDidLoad` redoes all of its work. How can I do that in Swift?

Comment: What's the point of doing that? Wouldn't it be easier to move the code that you wish to run in `viewDidLoad` into some other place, say, `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Might be. In that case, how do I get viewWillAppear to run again?

Comment: Why was this question down voted? Was it badly formed?

Comment: didn't downvote... but your question suggests that you didn't do proper research before asking the question. `viewDidLoad` is part of the view controller lifecycle and shouldn't be called multipiple times. maybe you can specify your actual problem a bit more.

Comment: I did do research. I was unable to find an answer, so I came here. I want to completely reload my view. Is that too much to ask?

Comment: certainly not! as I said, I didn't downvote but it's currently difficult to help you with the amount of information you gave us. the simplest advice I can give is to take all the code that you used in `viewDidLoad`, put in into a different method (e.g. `loadMyView`) and then call `loadMyView` from `viewDidLoad` as well as from the place where you want to reload the whole view...

Comment: you need to tell us, what it means to "reload your view" since this is not common terminology on iOS...

Comment: What I mean is that I want to make the view go away and then come back as if it had never been there before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75057/discussion-between-nburk-and-webmagnets).

Comment: this sounds more like you want to reset your view to its initial state, or do you literally want to get it off screen?

Comment: Reset to initial state.

Comment: then please follow the advice that I gave in my answer and that others already pointed out as well. or is there anything that you don't understand about it?

Comment: Well, I tried moving everything in the viewDidLoad to a loadData() function and then calling that function in viewDidLoad. That didn't seem to work. The reason I say that is because, before calling loadData(), I saved data to the database and the collection view datasource is created from the database. Anyway the cells weren't different when I called loadData().

Comment: when you are using a collection view, you can call `reloadData` on it

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I guess putting the view to its initial state doesn't work. What about getting it off the screen and then loading it back on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`viewViewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are part of the *view controller lifecycle* and are called automatically by iOS after your `UIViewController` got instantiated and before the view appears on the screen. You can call them anywhere in your view controller class, but that's not at all good practice and I would never recommend you to do so!

If you have code that you want to be executed at multiple times during the lifetime of your view controller, put it into separate methods and call these from `viewDidLoad` and from the other parts in your code where you need them.

You can read more about the view controller life cycle in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html).

Comment: I got it to work. Had to clear out my uicollectionview datasource first then call the separate method taken out of viewDidLoad.  Thanks.

Comment: What if in my application I am creating UI programmatically and in view controller I am adding all views from viewDidLoad method? In this case if I create common method then those views will get instantiated & added multiple times. So to avoid this I will have to remove each view, dealloc it and execute that method again. So there should be better alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `ViewDidLoad` manually but it is not recommended.
The best thing is to put all your code inside `viewDidLoad` in another methods (like `loadData`). And call this method again when you need it.

But it depends why you need it. Often `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewDidAppear` are a better choice.

Comment: What if in my application I am creating UI programmatically and in the viewController, I am adding all views from viewDidLoad method? In this case, if I create common method then those views will get instantiated & added multiple times. So to avoid this I will have to remove each view, dealloc it and execute that method again. So there should be a better alternative to this?