# Replace already presented View Controller with a new one seamlessly

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to find a way to replace an entire viewController which is already presented using `present()` with a new viewController object of same class.

I am trying to do this programmatically, please let me know how to clear all the `self.view` and other class variables and draw a fresh viewController with no trace of previous viewController.

Edit: Would also help if someone can answer ***how to clear a view controller(drawn views, class variables, everything) from within the view controller***?

Comment: share some code how to present your controller  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I completely reload a view so that viewDidLoad gets run again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590053/how-can-i-completely-reload-a-view-so-that-viewdidload-gets-run-again)

Answer (score -1):

It is unclear what you mean by "clear and draw fresh". But to replace a view simply do:

```
oldView.removeFromSuperview()
view.addSubview(newView)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

`let replaceView: UIView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view = replaceView`